# JAX-RS Option path param is not working

Tags: jax-rs

I am trying to use following construct

```
@ApplicationPath("app")
@Path("api/{userid}/model")
public class ModelService
{
   @Get
   @Path("{modelid: (.*)?}")
   public Response removePreProcessor(@PathParam("userid") String sUserId, @PathParam("preprocessorid") String sPreProcessorId)
   {
       return Response.build();
   }
}
```

I can not access both following REST URL

```
GET http://localhost:8080/XXXX/app/api/xyz/model
GET http://localhost:8080/XXXX/app/api/xyz/model/123
```

Let me know what is a wrong I am doing

-Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

As I read your question, several things look strange to me but they may be context related.

One thing though seems wrong :

You are using a `@PathParam("preprocessorid")` but I can't see this param in your path.

Do you have any logs ?